# Hallar un minimo entre dos numeros en haskell

Tags: haskell

Tengo un ejercicio donde tengo que hallar el mínimo entre dos naturales en Haskell.

Este es mi código, por alguna razón de esta manera siempre da cero:

```
mini= \x -> \y -> case x of{ O -> O; S f -> case y of{O -> O; S g-> mini f g }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mejor que uses una función auxiliar para tener accesibles los argumentos iniciales de la función. Además te evitarás usar los `case of`:

```hs
mini :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
mini x y = aux x y
  where
    aux 0 _ = x
    aux _ 0 = y
    aux (S a) (S b) = aux a b
``
```